# How do you kill a Xterm instance in Tiny window Manager using mouse pointer?

Tags: linux, xterm, twm

The only way I know is to use `exit` command to come out.

[image]

**Is there some way to close the Xterm windows using the GUI (the mouse pointer)?** Killing a lot of windows would be easier that way.

I am using [Tiny Window Manager](http://incise.org/tinywm.html).

Comment: If things like this are an issue, I'll go necro and plug [my own project](http://github.com/adamnew123456/SmallWM) here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from killing, `exit`ing is the only option. There is no GUI close button.

Answer (score 3):

Would [xkill](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-kill-x-windows-halted-frozen-or-resource-eating-application/) help?

Just type

```
xkill
```

and then left click on the window you want to close.

Answer (score 0):

there's a funny trick about that: type exit in another terminal and hover it including the line break with your mouse. You have now "exit\n" in the copy/paste buffer of X. Clicking any terminal with the middle button of your mouse will now terminate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your .twmrc:

```
RightTitleButton "xlogo11" = f.delete
```

Remember to change (yourname) to your username.